Use MoreThan between 2 columns
In a TypeORM project, I need to compare dates in 2 different columns in the database.
So I guess I have to use the MoreThan operator but the doc only shows how to compare a fixed value, like MoreThan(10). How do I compare 2 columns ?
Something like :
this.myRepository.find({
  where: {
    conversation: {
      lastMessage: {
        creationDate: MoreThan({otherTable: lastCheckTime})
      }
    }
  }
})

If possible, I would like to avoid expressions in a string, in order to preserve compilation checks
